# ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in ApiUsersController#create

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am not able to create new api_user. Everytime I try to create it I get

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: utf8, authenticity_token, api_user, commit, action, controller
```

here's my model `api_user.rb`

```
class ApiUser < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :api_key, :count, :email, :name, :organization
end
```

controller `api_users_controller.rb`

```
class ApiUsersController < ApplicationController
 #skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token

 def new
  @api_user = ApiUser.new
 end

 def create
    @api_user=ApiUser.create(params)
    render :text=>"#{@api_user.id}"
end

def destroy
    @api_user=ApiUser.find(params[:id])
    @api_user.destroy
    render :text=>"Deleted successfully"
end
 end
```

I am using Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3.2.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to create the ApiUser, you should use only the correct params:

```
@api_user=ApiUser.create(params[:api_user])
```

not all the `params`hash